# Is there a standard notation for the trivial loop in a fundamental group?

Tags: algebraic-topology, notation, fundamental-groups

Let $X$ be a topological space, let $x\in X$ and let $\pi_1 (X,x)$ be the fundamental group of $X$ with basepoint $x$.

Is there a standard notation for the trivial (constant) loop in $\pi_1 (X,x)$?

Generally speaking, I would denote the identity element of a group $G$ by $1_G$, but it seems cumbersome to write $1_{\pi_1 (X,x)}$ of course.

I also see loops typically denoted with Greek letters, so do most people just declare something like, "let $\gamma \in \pi_1 (X,x)$ be the (homotopy equivalence class of the) trivial loop", or is there a standard notation for this?

Comment: I would say that there’s no more need to denote the identity element by $1_{\pi(X, x)}$ then there is to denote the composition operator by $\cdot_{\pi(X, x)}$. Just denote the identity by $1$ in the same way you denote the group operation by $\cdot$.

Comment: There is no standard one, among the most common I've seen $c_x$ and $e_x$, but just $1$ would also be a perfectly legitimate notation

Comment: Rotman uses $i_x$ in his book "An Introduction to algebraic topology". I like it!

Comment: To answer your question, from three perfectly reasonable comments you can see that no, there is no standard notation. I would say: write clearly, state the meaning of your notation clearly, and you won't go wrong.